# webpack resolve module `blueimp-load-image` failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, webpack, blueimp

I'm trying to move from `browserify` to `webpack`, things are fine except one error:

```
[monson@Monson-MBP app]$ webpack -d
Hash: 4241a4e3680f13136bd3
Version: webpack 2.0.6-beta
Time: 4677ms
  Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
main.js  4.9 MB       0  [emitted]  main
 [371] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 371 hidden modules

ERROR in ./~/blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-meta.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'load-image' in '/Users/monson/project/elepro/app/node_modules/blueimp-load-image/js'
 @ ./~/blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-meta.js 22:8-39
[monson@Monson-MBP app]$ ll /Users/monson/project/elepro/app/node_modules/blueimp-load-image/js
total 112K
-rw-r--r-- 1 monson staff 4.6K 12 27 22:20 demo.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 monson staff  15K 12 28 00:35 load-image-exif-map.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 monson staff  11K 12 28 00:34 load-image-exif.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 monson staff 5.9K 12 28 00:37 load-image-ios.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 monson staff 6.4K 12 28 00:33 load-image-meta.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 monson staff 5.4K 12 28 00:37 load-image-orientation.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 monson staff  17K 12 28 07:13 load-image.all.min.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 monson staff  20K 12 28 07:13 load-image.all.min.js.map
-rw-r--r-- 1 monson staff  11K 12 28 00:29 load-image.js
drwxr-xr-x 4 monson staff  136  2  4 12:29 vendor
```

`webpack` cannot resolve 'load-image', but `load-image.js` is indeed inside the dir as you can see.

---

The module is imported in my code by

```
import loadImage from 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image'
import 'blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-meta'
```

Check `load-image-meta.js:18-29` below, it's `define(['load-image']` fails to resolve.

```
(function (factory) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // Register as an anonymous AMD module:
        define(['load-image'], factory);
    } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
        factory(require('./load-image'));
    } else {
        // Browser globals:
        factory(window.loadImage);
    }
}(function (loadImage) {
```

---

In my `webpack.config.js`, `resolve.extensions` is set right and `resolve.amd` isn't modified.
Actually, it is the only one module cannot be resolved, every others are fine.

Could any one point me to a direction? Thanks.

Additional Info: the trouble package 
https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image

Answer (score 1):

Setting `resolve.root` to `'/Users/monson/project/elepro/app/node_modules/blueimp-load-image/js'` fix it...

Answer (score 0):

You should import the whole module to have access to all its features:

import * as loadImage from  'blueimp-load-image'